# html element to separate php variable strings - ACF datepicker

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, variables, datepicker

i am using ACF to [display an internationalized date](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/) with this code :

```
<?php
    $dateformatstring = "l j F Y";
    $unixtimestamp = strtotime(get_field('date'));
?>

<?php echo date_i18n($dateformatstring, $unixtimestamp); ?>
```

but i wish i could separate each part into span for example to obtain a result like this :

```
<span>*day number*</span><span>*week day*</span><span>*month*</span><span>*year*</span>
```

but despite many attemps, i couldn't make it -_-
Thanks for your help ;-)

Comment: Why not just `echo '<span>'.date_i18n('..', $timestamp).'</span><span>'.date_i18n(...` (you get the idea) ?

Comment: yes i get it ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

thanks to @kero, i managed to do something like this :

```
<?php
    $dayNumber = "l";
    $weekDay = "j";
    $month = "F";
    $year = "Y";
    $unixtimestamp = strtotime(get_field('date'));
?>

<?php echo '<span>' . date_i18n($dayNumber, $unixtimestamp) . '</span>'; ?>
<?php echo '<span>' . date_i18n($weekDay, $unixtimestamp) . '</span>'; ?>
<?php echo '<span>' . date_i18n($month, $unixtimestamp) . '</span>'; ?>
<?php echo '<span>' . date_i18n($year, $unixtimestamp) . '</span>'; ?>
```

Not sure it is the best way to do it but it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There's another way to do it [as demonstrated here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-split-the-date-picker-value/):

- In ACF settings, use 'Custom Format' to separate the items you want to add HTML to with a comma

  - `M,d`
- In your output file, set up your date output as a variable

  - `$date = get_field(‘date’);`
- Next, [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the variable you created

  - `$dateArray = explode(‘,’, $date)`
- Use the array you created to add HTML to each piece of your date

  - `<p class="month"><?php echo $dateArray[0]; ?></p>`
  - `<p class="date"><?php echo $myArray[1]; ?></p>`
- Profit!